# nginx: how to create an alias url route?

Tags: nginx

basically an server instance is running at

```
somesite.com/production/folder/here?param=here&count=1
```

I want to point `someite.com/demo` to `/production/folder/here` so when user types `somesite.com/production/demo?param=here` it will work without redirecting to `/production/folder/here`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /path/to/root;
  location / {
    # bla bla
  }
  location /demo {
    alias /path/to/root/production/folder/here;
  }
}
```

If you need to use `try_files` inside `/demo` you'll need to replace `alias` with a `root` and do a rewrite because of the bug [explained here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias)

Comment: Does this only work for filesystem paths? what if the `/production/folder/here/` is an actual URL being served by a server instance? Would redirect be required?

Comment: If it's an actual URL then you want to `rewrite`, `alias` is used to point to a directory in the system

Comment: The documentation shows a cool trick with alias and regex: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Comment: ^ Link is broken in 2017. Not sure if it's fixed, I'm getting 404 so maybe it's still buggy

Comment: Redirect avoidable for URLs using proxy_pass

Comment: The "bug explained here" is 404.