# match all request nginx location

Tags: regex, nginx, location

I am trying to redirect any request for a sitemap.xml to a specific folder in nginx but I'm not able to write the right regular expression to do that.

I've tried several options and none of them worked. The one that seems to me that should work is:

```
location ~ \.xml$ {
    root /home/www/public/sitemaps;
}
```

But with this it just matches `http://localhost:8080/sitemap.xml` but it doesn't match something like `http://localhost:8080/other/sitemap.xml`.

How can I write the regular expression to match any URL that ends in sitemap.xml?

Thanks for your help.
/José Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the other regexp. If you have two regexp including "xml", nginx will use the "bigger" match between those two.

Anyway you can read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399789/nginx-how-to-create-an-alias-url-route). The first answer is telling you to try something like:

```
location /sitemap.xml {
    alias /home/www/public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml;
}
```

Comment: Not "bigger", but first.

Comment: It worked! Other problem that I had was that I didn't understand the difference between "alias" and "root". Thanks for your help.