# Nginx+apache. Different entry point

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I have Apache (listen 8888) and Nginx (listen 80).

In nginx.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  root /var/www/web/;
  ssi on;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

In apache conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
  LogLevel info
  ServerName testserver.localhost

  DocumentRoot /var/www/web/

  <Directory /var/www/web>
        AllowOverride none
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want two entry point.

1. testserver.localhost/forum/[anyfolders]/... would bring the index file in /var/www/forum/index.php
2. Any other would bring the index file in /var/www/web

What changes I need to make in nginx.conf and apache conf?

Comment: You can create aliases in your web configs (for both Apache and Nginx), so `/forum` simply points to another document root. For [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) and for [Nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399789/nginx-how-to-create-an-alias-url-route)

Comment: ok. I try in apache

        Alias /forum "/var/www/forum/"
     
     <Directory "/var/www/forum/">
     
          AllowOverride none
        
                DirectoryIndex index.php
        
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
     
     </Directory>
     
But it works only for testserver.localhost/forum/ and not work for testserver.localhost/forum/user/ etc.

Comment: It should take everything after /forum as well. I see that you have `AllowOverride None`, you don't happen to have any htaccess that's needed on that site? Otherwise, try `Alias /forum "/var/www/forum"` (without the last /).